# Read XLSX file data with Exceljs library

Tags: node.js, exceljs

Kindly see below code. I want to read data from xlsx file, worksheet name is : **WPA ext libs 2017.10.05**. for now I want to read values of first column. What changes should I do in code below?

please see [exceljs link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#reading-xlsx).

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");

var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("./CIoT_External Libraries & 3rd Party Content.xlsx")
.then(function(data){
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("WPA ext libs 2017.10.05");
    var lN = worksheet.getColumn(1);
    console.log(lN.collapsed);
});
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. If you see an error, please include it in the question.

Comment: I did't get any error. I got answer. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yoo.. I got answer. if someone knows better answer than this please let me know. :)

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");

var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("./CIoT_External Libraries & 3rd Party Content.xlsx" )
    .then(function(data){
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("WPA ext libs 2017.10.05");
        for(var v=1;v<=worksheet.actualRowCount;v++)
        {
            var lN = worksheet.getCell("B"+v).value;
            console.log(" V :"+v+"------ Name :" +lN);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to loop through the rows of an excel file using exceljs is using the builtin method .eachRow()

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("./CIoT_External Libraries & 3rd Party Content.xlsx" )
.then(function(data){
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("WPA ext libs 2017.10.05");

    worksheet.eachRow(function (row, rowNumber){
        // row_values contains the values, (first column is indexed by  
        var row_values = row_1.values;
        // Now you can access the columns directly by the column index
        Console.log("Value of Column B is : "+ row_values[2])
    }
 });
```